# How to pass int value from cell in to excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do something that is probably pretty simple.  I want to SUM the values in a column, but I want to stop summing at the cell number based on the INT value in another cell.  I tried this: =sum(A1:A(B1)) where the INT value is stored in cell B1, but it doesn't work.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX it is non-Volatile:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly.

Comment: For completeness sake, you could also use =SUM(OFFSET(A1,,,B1)). OFFSET is a very useful formula that can offset a reference by any number of rows and/or columns, and also return a range of any width and/or length. However, as Scott hinted, OFFSET is volatile, meaning Excel will always recalculate the cell based on any change. This is fine for small workbooks, but larger ones will slow down considerably. Because of OFFSET's variable nature, it has no way to determine a reliable dependency tree for the cell in order to optimise when to recalculate.